# Where is the Battery > Schedule panel in macOS Ventura?

Tags: battery, sleep-wake, ventura

I am used to set the Sleep mode to a certain hour to fall asleep while watching YouTube videos. I changed it regularly depending of the time I went to bed.

I can't find the *Schedule* tab anymore in the new System Settings app, macOS Ventura, have anyone found it ?

##### macOS 12.x (Monterey) battery panel with the Schedule tab :

[image: old battery panel in macOS System Preferences app]

##### macOS 13.0 (Ventura) new battery panel :

[image: macOS 13 new Battery panel in System Settings app]

Comment: open to edit and/or different answers before accepting mine

Comment: Big Sur is 11.x. 12.x is Monterey.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I should have search more efficiently before asking.

Rapidly came across [this article](https://www.macobserver.com/tips/how-to/how-to-schedule-your-mac-to-shutdown-or-reboot-in-macos-ventura/) from The Mac Observer. The author explains the option has been removed by Apple :

> Until recently, setting your Mac on a shutdown or reboot schedule was easy. You just needed to go into the Energy Saver panel in System Preferences, and use the graphical interface to set up that schedule. Strangely enough, Apple doesn’t include that same functionality in macOS Ventura.

See also DssW's [Missing Energy Saver Schedule in macOS 13](https://dssw.co.uk/blog/2022-10-25-energy-saver-schedule-ventura/).

I can't find any mention of removal in the [macOS 13.0 release note](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/macos-release-notes/macos-13-release-notes).

Except the fact GUI is for now removed, this option still is controllable using the `pmset` command, that has been often [questioned](https://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=pmset) on AskDifferent.

Here is a [link](https://www.dssw.co.uk/reference/pmset/) to DssW website for documentation or type `man pmset` into a terminal to see available options.

For example, the following command would reboot the computer every monday at 2AM.

```
sudo pmset repeat restart M 02:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your goal by making the necessary changes:

[image]

and then:

[image]

Comment: While this does not answer the original question regarding scheduling, it answers my question to find this exact setting - not putting computer into sleep when monitor is turned off. Thank you.